# getting jp2 images from mysql database and displaying in a web page using php

Tags: php, mysql

Iam unable to display jp2 image in web page.

This is main file to get image from database and display it in to web page.

**In database images are in the format of JP2 image format.**

```
      <?php
        echo' <html>';
         echo'<body>';
         echo' <table>';
         echo' <tr><td>';

       $dbcnx = @mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root@19211');
         if (!$dbcnx) {
           die('<p>Unable to connect to the ' . 'database server at this time.</p>'
        );
            }
         if (!@mysql_select_db('finaldb')) {
               die('<p>Unable to locate the ' . 'database at this time.</p>');
             }

              $selectrc = 'select BPFT_Photo from photo_templates limit 1';
              $result = @mysql_query($selectrc, $dbcnx);
             if (!$result) {
               die('<p>Error performing query: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');
                } else {

             }
         $n = mysql_num_rows($result);

            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

              $Photo_Details = $row['BPFT_Photo'];

           $residentPhoto = getResidentPhoto();
           $image_type_to_mime_type0 =image_type_to_mime_type($residentPhoto)
           header('Content-type:$image_type_to_mime_type0');

           echo' '.$residentPhoto;

           echo'</td>';
           echo'</tr>';
           echo'</table>';
           echo'</body>';
           echo'</html>';
          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

jp2 image must supported in browser or you cant see..

and what method you used to add it in a webpage

(i think you used echo) .but echo will nothing do only write some charecters into a webpage

you must get image from database and save it in a temporary folder in server and echo the path to web

example :

```
 $path="root/tmp/photo.jp2";
 echo '<img src=$path>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent
```

the above line comes from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).
You're using a header request, yet you already echoed some data so the headers already sent.

If you want to display **JP2** data, you have 2 options:

- Read the data from database, then create a *temporary* file (with say. [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents), then load the image with an `<img>` tag.
- Use the `header(Content-type)` method but outputing only the image data, without tables and other than *JP2 raw data*.

**UPDATE:**

Also look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support) about the *very tiny* support for JPEG-2000 format, after years and years. I would change my mind about *JP2 usage* on web if i were you..